# How do I move FastAPI OAuth functions to a class without getting "self" being interpreted as an API parameter?

Tags: python, oauth, fastapi

I am adding OAuth to a simple web app, and worked through the excellent FastAPI security tutorial (https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/security/). However, in their tutorial, everything is in a single script. I'd like to move all my authentication methods to a AuthService class. This class does things like connect to a user collection in my database, performs password hashing, and also creates the OAuth scheme (using `OAuth2PasswordBearer` from `fastapi.security`).

I am succesfully able to move everything over to this class, except for a couple functions. In my routes/ directory, I have these two functions that handle getting user info. You can see they both reference the `auth_service` object I mentioned before:

```
async def get_current_user(token: str = Depends(oauth2_scheme)):
    credentials_exception = HTTPException(
        status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
        detail="Could not validate credentials",
        headers={"WWW-Authenticate": "Bearer"},
    )
    try:
        payload = jwt.decode(token, os.getenv('SECRET_KEY'), algorithms=[os.getenv('ALGORITHM')])
        email: str = payload.get("sub")
        if email is None:
            raise credentials_exception
        token_data = TokenData(email=email)
    except JWTError:
        raise credentials_exception
    user = auth_service.get_user(email=token_data.email)
    if user is None:
        raise credentials_exception
    return user

async def get_current_active_user(current_user: User = Depends(get_current_user)):
    if current_user.disabled:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Inactive user")
    return current_user
```

When I try to move these methods to the `AuthService` class, I suddenly don't know what to do with my endpoints. For example, this was previously:

```
@router.get("/users/me", response_model=User)
async def read_users_me(current_user: User = Depends(get_current_active_user)):
    return current_user
```

And in the API docs, no parameters show up (presumably because there is no active user?). But now, when I replace `get_current_active_user` with `auth_service.get_current_active_user` the API shows up as requiring an email/password/etc for this endpoint. So I'm a bit confused.

So basically — is there any way to put ALL my auth methods into an AuthService class?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is possible to convert these functions into 'classmethods' within your AuthService class. In that case you don't need to instantiate the AuthService class.

So something like:

```
class AuthService:

    @classmethod
    async def get_current_user():
    ....
```